# How to assign conditional values to angular material Multi Select?

Tags: angular-material, angular8, multi-select

I need the following functionally in material multi-select:

1. Once None is selected - all the checkboxes are unchecked and 'None' is obviously selected,
2. But once any value , other than 'None' is selected - the 'None' is unchecked and all the selected items are selected as usual.
3. Also None should be the preselect value incase nothing is selected...

So - the first issue i did in 2 ways :
1 - Added 'None' to my list and on the change function - deselecting all the rest
2 - Added another option markup with it's own logic

```
    <mat-option #noneSelected (click)="toggleNone()" [value]="0">None</mat-option>
```

Problem is i don't know how to check and uncheck material items programmatically - i've tried with ref element - to get the dom element and check / uncheck it, but since it's material element - it's not that straight forward ....

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v3df1u?file=app%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to manipulate dom just use `(selectionChange)`event emitter to detect changes [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v3df1u-x5dink?file=app/select-custom-trigger-example.ts)'s how it should be done

Comment: Thanks - but it's not working - the goal is if 'None' is selected - than once any value other than 'None' is selected - the 'None' will be unchecked, perhaps i didn't explained myself correctly

Comment: okay, I edited the [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v3df1u-x5dink?file=app/select-custom-trigger-example.ts) to behave as you expect and extra cheese is the default value if nothing is selected